# Python zipapp with native extensions

Tags: python

You can use zipapp to package apure  Python application into a zip file.
You can also include pure Python library modules into that zip.

The problem is that including libraries which contain native modules (.so in Linux) does not work: Python is not able to load the .so from the zip file (because the OS wants to load the native modules from a file) and Python is also not able to do load the .so from the file system (when the rest of the package is coming from the .zip file.

Is there a way to make Python load the .so files from the file system and the rest of the package from the .zip file?

(I know that PyInstaller/py2exe does similar things, but I want to control the boot loader)